# MVC 5 Web Attribute Routing is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I implemented the Attribute routing in my Application and after that when I started nothing was working as planned. Only the Json Results works rest is not working as expected.

```
 [RoutePrefix("ProductCategory")]
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
      [Route("CategoryMain")]
        // GET: /Category/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var cat = categoryService.GetCategories();

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("Index", cat);
            }
            return View("Index", cat);
        }
    }
```

Error

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ProductCategory/MainIndex
I've also tried with Just Index even that is not working now

But if The method is JsonResult it will return me the data in json format. Its not working on any other ActionResults
  **My RouteConfig**

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
```

**My webapiConfig**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

**My Global**

```
 AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Autofac and Automapper configurations
        Bootstrapper.Run();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the route prefix and route below

```
[RoutePrefix("ProductCategory")]
public class CategoryController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("CategoryMain")] // Matches GET ProductCategory/CategoryMain
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var cat = categoryService.GetCategories();
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            return PartialView("Index", cat);
        }
        return View("Index", cat);
    }
}
```

The requested URL needs to be

```
ProductCategory/CategoryMain
```

for the `CategoryController.Index` Action

Comment: Ironically this worked. One question please "Why did the documentation said If there is nothing defined then by default its [HttpGet]

Comment: That is for convention-based routing. If using attribute routing and there may be multiple actions you need to specify the HTTP Verb so the routing table knows how to deal with the request.

Comment: @Nkosi is it possible to send this request using productcategory only, means omitting categorymain , i have made the function name as index but it does not work , some thing missing may be

Comment: @Dragon use `[Route("")] // Matches GET ProductCategory` using the empty string as the route template.