# Can't get Route to work in ASP.Net Web API 2 when inheriting Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I'm trying to get this to work in my ASP.Net Web API 2 application. You will notice that this Controller inherits Controller. This is because I need to return a View instead of JSON.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Manage")]
public class ManageController : Controller
{
  [Route("TestOne")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> MyTestOne(string value1, string value2)
  {
    return View("");
  {
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting.

```
<error>
<MessageDetail> No type was found that matches the controller named 'Manage'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I need to call the Manage Controller like so.

https://api.domain.com/api/Manage/TestOne?value1=foo&value2=bar

My RouteConfig is configured like so.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

NOTE: [RoutePrefix("api/Account")] works in my AccountController. This is an API Controller and inherits ApiBase.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can just add [RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")] to allow the RouteConfig to do his own work.

Comment: Can you explain more why you need to return a _View_ and how you are calling this Api action. It sounds weird.

Comment: Attribute routing will override the traditional router, so not sure why RouteConfig is provided here

Comment: @pmcilreavy I'm calling this from a URL in an email. Instead of returning Ok("Success"), I need to return a View with a message that can be read. The View then needs to be closed by JavaScript.

Comment: Try adding `[FromQuery]` in front of each string parameter, i.e. `MyTestOne([FromQuery] string value1, [FromQuery] string value2)`. This will give a hint to asp.net to get these values from the querystring.

Comment: @Daniel I assume it is needed to return the Index page for the HomeController. The Index page then links to API instructions etc...

Comment: @HamletLeon Thanks, but [RoutePrefix("api/[Controller]")] did not work.

Comment: @pmcilreavy I can't add [FromQuery]. It could not be found.

Comment: @Dumber_Texan2 did you add the controller with the Add Controller option of the VStudio ? If you are using VSCode do you create the folder of that controller in Views?

Comment: If I add [RoutePrefix("Manage")], it works as expected. This leads me to believe that perhaps RouteConfig is overriding AttributeRouting or something.

Comment: @HamletLeon Yes, I added an empty MVC 5 Controller using VS. I then added the View. The controller and View works if I hit it like so. https://api.domain.com/Manage/TestOne?value1=foo&value2=bar

Comment: That happends becouse you need to add rules to RouteConfig that allows that your others parameters need to be optionals. If you add [FromQuery] on each parameter or use a class to manage it, you could access without parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you have 2 route configuration, one for `MVC` controllers and one for `Web API`. And in your case `Web API` route configuration goes first. `Global.asax.cs` looks like this

```
//some configs
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
//some configs
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

And you must be having something like this in `Web API` route config

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

When you request `/api/Manage/TestOne` the `Web API` routing applies first. No attribute based route fits but the request perfectly matches to `DefaultApi` route. `Manage` matches to `{controller}` and `TestOne` goes to `{id}`. So the framework starts searching for api controller with name `Manage` like this

```
public class ManageController : ApiController
```

But there is not such controller and indeed you have an error

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://host/api/Manage/TestOne/?value1=foo&value2=bar'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Manage'."
}
```

So I can suggest you few possible solutions.

**Change route configuration order**

```
//some configs
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
//some configs
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

And then your example will work as expected but it may create unexpected errors because I don't know all possibles routes in your application.

**Remove `DefaultApi` route**

If you completely rely on attribute based routing for `Web API` you can just remove this configuration with no negative effect for you application

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Or just change prefix**

If you change prefix from `api` to anything else it will work as well because it won't match `DefaultApi` route anymore

```
[RoutePrefix("view/Manage")]
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up reformatting the URLs I was generating to work with my Default RouteConfig, but you are on the right track with your answer. I actually found this Stackoverflow that first alerted me to the existence of dueling configs. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120965/mvc-5-web-attribute-routing-is-not-working